# picture tag in polymer-element not working

Tags: html, image, media-queries, polymer

I wanted to create a polymer-element that uses the picture tag.

Sadly it does not work as expected. The media-query does not work at all.
Does anybody have experience with this?
I also tried resolution media-query because I was not sure that the element had access to the actual viewport, but it will just ignore the `<source>` as soon as `<source media>` is set.

Live example: http://codepen.io/pixelass/pen/QwdBxX

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.5.2/polymer.min.js"></script>
<polymer-element name="polymer-picture">
  <script>Polymer('polymer-picture',{});</script>
  <template>
    <picture>
      <source srcset="http://placehold.it/50" media="(max-width:399px)"/>
      <source srcset="http://placehold.it/80" media="(max-width:599px)"/>
      <source srcset="http://placehold.it/100" media="(max-width:799px)"/>
      <source srcset="http://placehold.it/150" media="(max-width:999px)"/>
      <source srcset="http://placehold.it/200"/><img alt="My default image"/>
    </picture>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
<h1>&lt;picture&gt; tag inside custom polymer-element breaks</h1>
<h2>Polymer element does not work</h2>
<polymer-picture></polymer-picture>
<h2>HTML5 element works</h2>
<picture>
  <source srcset="http://placehold.it/50" media="(max-width:399px)"/>
  <source srcset="http://placehold.it/80" media="(max-width:599px)"/>
  <source srcset="http://placehold.it/100" media="(max-width:799px)"/>
  <source srcset="http://placehold.it/150" media="(max-width:999px)"/>
  <source srcset="http://placehold.it/200"/><img alt="My default image"/>
</picture>
```

Comment: fixed: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=446876

Comment: @alexanderfarkas nice find. I was looking left and right in google and couldn't find an issue. It is in fact fixed in Chrome Canary. Feel free to post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it